# Google Protocol Buffers Extension work in old files

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers, header-files

Ok, I have a protocol buffers files test.cc, test_extend.pb.cc

```
using namespace std;


#include "test.pb.h"

#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h>
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
#include <google/protobuf/message.h>
#include <google/protobuf/dynamic_message.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const google::protobuf::Descriptor* logged_msg_descriptor_;
static google::protobuf::Message* logged_msg_;
static google::protobuf::DynamicMessageFactory* dynamic_message_factory_;

void process(BaseType * msg){

    const google::protobuf::Descriptor* message_desc = msg->GetDescriptor();
    const google::protobuf::Reflection* ref = msg->GetReflection();


    for (int extension_number = 0; extension_number < message_desc->extension_range_count(); extension_number++) {
        const google::protobuf::Descriptor::ExtensionRange* rng = message_desc->extension_range(extension_number);

        std::cerr << "ref " << ref << " rng->start " << rng->start << " rng->end " << rng->end << std::endl;
        for (int extension_indx = rng->start; extension_indx <= rng->end; extension_indx++){
            std::cerr << "extension_indx " << extension_indx << std::endl;
            const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* field_descriptor = ref->FindKnownExtensionByNumber(extension_indx);
            std::cerr << "field_descriptor " << field_descriptor << std::endl;

            if (field_descriptor)
            {
                std::cout << field_descriptor->type();
                // std::cerr << " " << ref->HasField(*logged_msg_, field_descriptor) << std::endl;
            }

            if (field_descriptor && ref->HasField(*msg, field_descriptor)){
                std::cout << "Non null field_descriptor found " << field_descriptor->name() << std::endl;
                std::cout << field_descriptor->number() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Then I have main file.

```
#include "test_extend.pb.h"
#include "main.cpp"


int main(){


    set_things();

    const google::protobuf::Reflection* ref1 = logged_msg_->GetReflection();

    // adding fields to the log message
    const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* fd = logged_msg_->GetDescriptor()->FindFieldByName("name");
    ref1->SetString(logged_msg_, fd, "whee");
    const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* field_descriptor = ref1->FindKnownExtensionByName("price");

    if(field_descriptor){
        ref1->SetFloat(logged_msg_, field_descriptor , 22.0);
    }

    // BaseType * b = (BaseType *)logged_msg_;

    // b->set_name("testing");

    // if(b->HasExtension(price)){
    //     b->SetExtension(price,99);
    // }

    // test();

    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    process( (BaseType*) logged_msg_);

    return 0;
}
```

The BaseType* is defined in test.proto and it is extended in test_extend.ptoto.

My question is that `process()` does not know the static as well as dynamic type new `BaseType` . So how is this printing all the extended fields in process() function.

Comment: Do you also have a question?

Comment: If you look at the code, it is retrieving the Descriptor from the actual message (I presume it is a self describing message). Then in process it loops through all the extension fields.

Comment: Yes the message passed is self describing. But If you see the first file, only ``#include "test.pb.h"`` is included(not ``#include "test_extend.pb.h"``). so this file have no access to extended fields yet. So how does it return correct output.

Comment: It doesn't matter what headers a particular source file includes - that's not where the reflection metadata lies. You have compiled both `test.pb.cc` and `test_extend.pb.cc`, and linked them into your binary - that's where the metadata comes from. One can perform reflection starting with nothing but `google::protobuf::Message*`.